# How to make two into one list comprehension statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am scraping text rendered in an HTML page. I using list comprehension to handle the text data coming from the HTML page.

I am grabbing two different objects (data,data2) from the web page, I want to write both of those objects into their own list.

```
data= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[5]')
data2=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[6]')
```

I am using selenium webdriver so when the objects return I need to iterate through the object and grab all the text (that is what is happening in the first round of list comprehension where I assign the lists to the variable text and text2).

```
text = [i.text for i in data]

text2 = [i. text for i in data2]
```

After the first list comprehension the list returns as the following

```
['Running\nRunning Normally\nShavings\n47.6%\n739\n739\n3:38:53\n1:31:51\n0:00:00']
```

I want to split the contents of that string into a list so that's why I followed up with a second list comprehension.

```
text=[i.split("\n")[:] for i in text]

text2=[i.split("\n")[:] for i in text2]
```

When I print the list it returns

```
[['Running Slow', 'Slow and/or Small Stops', 'Shavings', '48.7%', '800', '800', '3:56:43', '1:31:51', '0:00:00']]
```

Any suggestions on how to clean this up or make it work better?

Code:

```
data= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[5]')
data2=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[6]')

text = [i.text for i in data]

text2 = [i. text for i in data2]

text=[i.split("\n")[:] for i in text]

text2=[i.split("\n")[:] for i in text2]

print(text)
print(text2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should work, but I cant try it since I don't have the data:

```
text=[j for i in data for j in i.text.split("\n")]
text2=[j for i in data2 for j in i.text.split("\n")]
```